# Can I set a python variable using data from the parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters

```
def convertWeight(value, unit, unitToConvert) -> converterdWeight:
    convertor = w(unit = 0)
    unitValue = w(unit = value)
    return convertor + unitValue
convertWeight(20, 'g', 'oz')
```

This uses the measurements module, it defines a variable in the function, e.g. Weight(kg = 10).

I want to make the function so thart the parameters do this so,

```
def func(parameter):
    weight(parameter = 10)
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

```
var = 0
def func(variableToChange):
    Weight(**{variableToChange : 1})
```

Var is now 1!